# SQL For-each Loop Alternative

Tags: sql

I have two tables (let's call them TradingWindows and VolumeData).  Each row of TradingWindows has a startBin and endBin for each different stock.  In VolumeData, there are columns stock,binIndex,volume.

I want to combine this information by doing the following operation:  for-each row in the TradingWindows table I want to sum up the all the volume binIndex's that are > startBin and < endBin.  (the idea is to get the total volume between start and end).

Now, coming from a procedural programming background this is easy (just write a for-each loop).  I know this is possible in SQL, but I am new and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: We need more info on your table structure and how you want to aggregate the data... it would help to see how you might do it with a loop.

Comment: YOu want to forget that loops and cursors exist while you are learning to query databases. THey are very opoor techiniques for data processing and should not be used by anyone below the expert level who understands the trade-offs in using them. For SQL Server, I'd estimate that 95% or more of all sql query tasks can be done in a set-based fashion more efficiently and with less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making some guesses on your table structure, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Select VD.stock, Sum(volume)
From VolumeData VD
    Inner Join TradingWindows TW On VD.stock = TW.stock
Where VD.binIndex Between TW.startBin And TW.endBin
Group By VD.stock
```

This will match up your VolumeData rows to your TradingWindow rows (by stock), filter out the VolumeData rows which aren't in your range, and group them together by stock.

EDIT: Here's a non-inclusive version (as JNK points out, BETWEEN will include startBin and endBin):

```
 Select VD.stock, Sum(volume)
    From VolumeData VD
        Inner Join TradingWindows TW On VD.stock = TW.stock
    Where VD.binIndex > TW.startBin And VD.binIndex < TW.endBin
    Group By VD.stock
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the tables are super large (lots and lots of rows in both tables).  Won't this blow up?

Comment: +1, but one minor quibble - It looks like OP wants to **not** include `startbin` and `endbin` based on the description, so you may not want to use `BETWEEN` since it's inclusive.

Comment: @user1167650 - SQL is designed for operations on large sets of data.  What you think is "lots and lots of rows" probably isn't that much.  I have tables with billions of rows that `JOIN` just fine.  Also, if you have appropriate indexes it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: I'm dealing with a something on the order of a billion rows, so would just like to understand a bit more about how SQL processes.  If I had a condition to the WHERE statement WHERE TD.date = x, will it process that before trying to do the join?  (This might be obvious, but would just like to confirm)

Comment: @user1167650 - I would say open a new question on that.  The short answer to your example is "maybe".  There's also a site dba.stackexchange.com for questions on SQL internals or administration.